# Apple devices pick up wrong date from iCal file

Tags: drupal, icalendar

I'm producing iCal events through the [Drupal calendar module](http://drupal.org/project/calendar). I can import it without problems into Thunderbird and Korganizer on a Kubuntu machine. But on Macs and also on an iPhone, the event wasn't recognized correctly. The event is imported, but the date used as start date ist DTSTAMP instead of DTSTART. An almost identical ics file from another website (Typo3) works without problems, though. Here are the two files:

This one works:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//TYPO3/NONSGML Calendar Base (cal) V1.3.2//EN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:www.example.com_4_46252
DTSTAMP:20120530T090015
DTSTART:20120723T170000Z
DTEND:20120723T170001Z
SUMMARY:The Title
DESCRIPTION:Here is the description.
LOCATION:Some location
ORGANIZER;CN=Name:MAILTO:email@example.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

And this one doesn't:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
PRODID:-//Drupal iCal API//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:calendar.52399.field_date.0.0
SUMMARY:The Title
DTSTAMP:20120624T200438Z
DTSTART:20120723T170000Z
DTEND:20120723T170000Z
URL;VALUE=URI:http://example.com
LOCATION:Some location
DESCRIPTION:Here is the description.
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Any hints where I could find the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I copied your Drupal-created ical code into a new file, test.ics, and opened it in Mac OS10.5 iCal and it worked correctly.

Try this:

Open the file in the VI editor through the terminal, and look for ^M (ctrl-M) characters.  If they're there, try removing them (http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/150/remove-m-characters-at-end-of-lines-in-vi/) and re-opening the file.

Comment: Thanks for that hint. There actually _are_ ^M in the file that causes problems. After a first short test, deleting them seems to solve the problem. But I'll confirm that. Now the question would be, how to tell Drupal/Calendar module not to use them.